# Máscara em campo texto sem usar jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

Alguém conhece alguma gem para ROR que faça esse trabalho ? Adicione mascaras para campos como telefone, e-mail, data, etc e que permita que eu também crie minhas próprias mascaras. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Sinceramente, não acredito que exista alguma, pois as máscaras devem ser feitas do lado cliente, e as *gems* geralmente atuam no lado servidor.
Eu utilizo uma *gem*, mas ela nada mais é do que o jQuery carregado no projeto, funciona semelhante ao `bootstrap-rails`.

A biblioteca de máscara carregada no sistema é o [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

Recomendo a *gem* [Jquery::Inputmask::Rails](https://github.com/marcosnogueira/jquery-inputmask-rails) por ser bem útil e bem documentada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar mascadas do htlm, com o parâmetro pattern.

Exemplo:

```
<%= ff.text_field :telefone_comercial, placeholder: '(DD)1234-5678', pattern: '\([0-9]{2}\)[0-9]{4,6}-?[0-9]{3,4}$' %>
```

A mascara é feita por regex. http://html5pattern.com/ Neste link existem vários padrões já escritos.